# Harder question, when missing an expert are far less treated, even if they are "good" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties, experts

Easy question are answered quite quickly, there's a small competition on them, to get easy reputation points...
But these will usually get zero score.

**Better** questions, which are usually harder, get higher scores, which gives motivation to ask better questions in the 1st place.

Here's the thing, if there are fewer experts on certain topics,
There's less scoring on the questions and less solutions on questions that are a little harder.

The only solution that I'm familiar with, is the bounties, but isn't there any other mechanism, to encourage more experts to arrive to the site in the 1st place?

This is true less for StackOverflow - more depending on the specific field
But even more so on sites with less users and less traffic...

Comment: What question are you asking here?

Comment: How to get experts to treat harder questions, how to encourage more experts to arrive to StackExchange sites in the 1st place...

Comment: There's no feature request here, it's just an open ended discussion. Retagged.

Comment: Relative topic, but not the same... as I am not asking about the score as end, but as a mean... bottom line, I need help that I am not getting...

Comment: After reading the other question and its answers, I marked it as duplicate, now the my wonder is how come it received a high score, while mine received a negative score...

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to attract experts to answer any question, from easy to hard, is by asking a single clear question so that they can say to themselves:

> I understand their question and I know the answer (or how to determine it) so I'll start working on it.

If by "hard" you mean one that is poorly explained, then a bounty may be the only way that you can entice someone to volunteer additional time to discern what it is asking before they can decide whether to answer.

Comment: By hard I mean more challenging, though the proper formulation of a question is good remark